# Why do we care about $G_{\delta}$ sets?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

In a topological space $X$, a set $U\subseteq X$ is called $G_{\delta}$ if it is a countable intersection of open sets. What is the intuition behind this definition? Why should we give special care to these kind of sets?

Answer (score 1):

These sets are special class of [Borel Sets](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_set). Borel sets are crucial as they form a $\sigma$-algebra on which useful measures like probability measures, Borel measures etc. can be defined. They also come in handy in Baire's Category theorem and related areas. Again, they are useful in descriptive set theory.